# Add Logging (to a DB) to Service Stack Service

Tags: logging, servicestack

I am new to Service Stack and have created my first service to replace a WebAPI service.  The service will be readonly and will mostly be consumed with the `JsonServiceClient`.  I'm using version 4 of Service Stack.

I have a requirement to log several things about each request to a database - request variables (`HTTP_USER_AGENT`, `LOGON_USER`, etc.), the response code, response content type, the response time (ms), number of records returned (if applicable), etc.

I'm looking for some "global" way of achieving this (without putting a lot of code in each service/method).

Has anyone done this kind of logging before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to use a `GlobalRequestFilter` and a `GlobalResponseFilter` which you can setup in your `AppHost`'s `Configure` method. [See here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters) for more information about filtering requests.

The code below shows the basic constructs and all the data you should need about the request and response is available to you.

```cs
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
    ...

    // Record the time the request started.
    this.GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, requestDto) => req.SetItem("StartTime", DateTime.Now));

    // The request has been processed, ready to send response
    this.GlobalResponseFilters.Add((req, res, responseDto) => {

        // Get the start time that was recorded when the request started
        var startTime = req.GetItem("StartTime") as DateTime;

        // Determine the duration of the request
        var duration = DateTime.Now - startTime;

        // You can use req.Headers to access things like the HTTP_USER_AGENT

        // If you are returning a IList of results then you can determine 
        // the number of records you are returning from the responseDto
        var list = responseDTO as IList;
        if(list != null){
            // Response is a list
            // Record the count using list.count
        }

        /* 
         * Passing additional information:
         * If you need to make information from within your service methods available
         * here then you can use Request.SetItem() and access it here using req.GetItem()
         */

         // Save the log to the database
    });
}
```

I hope this is a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at the built in [RequestLogsFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-logger) in ServiceStack.  By default, it keeps a rolling list of your requests in memory; however, you can create your own implementation of `IRequestLogger` that will save to a database.  You can easily implement it by adding the feature like this:

```
Plugins.Add(new RequestLogsFeature { RequiredRoles = new string[] { } });
```

The `RequestLogsFeature` features a simple service that will show the last `N` items of your service at /requestlogs; however, if you just want to be able to save information to your database, you can skip this by registering your own request logger manually.

```
in your Service Hosts's Configure method:
Register<IRequestLogger>(new MyRequestLogger());
```